# How to re-order Listeners for OnClick in the Inspector?

Tags: unity-game-engine, button

I'm currently having an issue with unity UI.

I have some buttons to who I've added an instruction in `OnClick` directly in the editor, but because it is in the last position in the list of instructions, it is executed at a poor time.

I would like to know if there is a way to move these instructions up and down, as to change the order in which they are executed ?

I've tried to slide them up and down to no avail, and no amount of google searches seem to help. 
Feel free to ask any questions if you need more specific information !

---

**Edit** : Added a screenshot. I want to move the items in the circled area up and down if possible without having to delete it all and restart...

Screenshot of the hierarchy with concerned area circled:

[image]

Comment: Please post any image of your hierarchy, code, etc so it facilitates the debuging

Comment: No there isn't ^^ It is a huge flaw of the default drawer for `UnityEvent` that these elements are not re-orderable ... You could implement a custom drawer for this but yeah well ...

Comment: Seriously, there's no way ? Jeez, huge flaw is an understatement...and everything was going so well. 
I'm posting a screenshot in case it helps Lotan !

Answer (score 1):

Even if you were able to reorder events, order doesn't mean execution order.

https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-unityevent-invoke-calling-order.265292/#post-1753393

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help ! I'll have to figure something out then.